# SQL translated into fluent Nhibernate => joining with static values

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to turn this sql statement into a fluent nhibernate mapping :

```
select *
from Project p
inner join ProjectData pd on p.Project = pd.Project
inner join ProjectCompany pc on p.Project = pc.Project and pc.InitComp = 'Yes' and pc.Company = pd.LogComp
inner join ProjectCustomer cust on cust.id = pd.custid
```

I'm facing a number of problems for getting this statement into a single entity(all joins are a 1 on 1 relationship).
I am aware that a single view would solve my issues but alas i don't have the privileges to create one.

Currently my code looks like this

```
Table("Project");
Id(p=> p.Number);
Join("ProjectData", j =>
{
    j.Fetch.Join();
    j.KeyColumn("Project");
    j.Map(pd => pd.Customer);
});
Map(p => p.Complexity);
```

The problems i am facing are :

- How do i create a hard coded filter (pc.InitComp = 'Yes')
- How do i join with 2 statements(p.project = pc.Project and pc.Company = pd.LogComp
- How do i join from a joined table rather then the base one?(ProjectCustomer joins on ProjectData)

A lot of questions for something so trivial in sql but i can't seem to find a simple answer on the internet other then create a view.

Comment: nhibernate does not support filter in join mapping. one solution is to use a private reference to a class ProjectData and implement the logic in the getter/setter of Customer

Comment: That is a bummer, main reason i wanted to do so was to create 1 fast query so working with custom getter/setter won't give the benefit i need. Thank you for pointing this out though, guess i will have to beg the dba's to let me create a view.

Comment: a `<manytoone lazy="false">` is almost the same as `<join>`

Comment: I see your point but i'd still have to manage 4 entities with private references to each other and custom getters to expose my data. Besides that i'd have to make add filters to these private references which might be something that ,just as with a join, won't work. For me it seems to be getting at a point where i won't find my solution elegant anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a raw sql query and using a datareader to manually fill my object.
This worked cause i only needed to read from a table and not write.